# Differential Notation on Inner Products of 4-Vectors

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

I genuinely cannot for the life of me make sense of the variation of the action on [this page](http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=X18PF4oKyrUC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=landau%20electromagnetic%20field%20tensor%20%22the%20limits%20of%20integration%20are%20omitted%20for%20brevity%22&source=bl&ots=Jt7UNuPRs8&sig=OcsD9sOd0ZnGM-PwLEa3fnw0DEQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1E3VUZzEB4ikO4KQgbgD&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> How does $$\delta ds \ = \ \delta \sqrt{dx_idx^i} \ = \ \frac{dx_i d \delta x^i}{ds}$$

How would you explain this result rigorously in a way that makes sense of whatever is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it's done:

$$ds = \sqrt{dx_i dx^i}$$
$$\delta ds = \delta \sqrt{dx_idx^i} = \frac{\delta \left(dx_i dx^i \right)}{2 \sqrt{dx_idx^i}}$$
Now we have to calculate $\delta \left(dx_i dx^i \right)$:

$$\delta \left(dx_i dx^i \right)=\delta \left(g_{ij}dx^j dx^i \right)=g_{ij}\left( \delta{dx^j}\ dx^i+dx^j \ \delta{dx^i}\right)$$
But the metric is symmetric, therefore:
$$\delta \left(dx_i dx^i \right)=2 g_{ij} dx^j \ \delta{dx^i}=2dx_i \delta{dx^i}$$

So we have:
$$\delta{ds}= \frac{2 dx_i \delta{dx^i}}{2 \ ds}= \frac{dx_i  \delta dx^i}{ds}$$

But $\delta$ and $d$ can move through each other, therefore:

$$\delta{ds}=\frac{dx_i d \delta x^i}{ds}.$$

Comment: How is $\delta(dx_idx^i) \ = \ 2dx_i \delta dx^i$? I don't understand how you differentiate that.

Comment: @bolbteppa I see, I will add that to my solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was driving me crazy!

Comment: @bolbteppa You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.